# link to a specific section of a js controlled page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have tried to look for this, but I am not sure exactly how to phrase what I am looking for, so please excuse me if this is a duplicate question. I have a .php page with 5 divs that are link controlled by jquery. loading the page initially has the home div displayed and the rest hidden. Clicking on a link causes the home div to fade and the new div to show in it's place using a jquery script called at the bottom of the page. It is also shown in the url as http://example.com/#visible-div. What I would like to be able to do is link to the page and have a specific section load. For example, if I link to http://example.com/#div4, then the page will load with div4 showing. I was thinking that by using a php get command at the beginning, I could get the request and load it, but I am not sure how I would go about that. Here is my existing code:

```
<div class="menulistbot">
        <ul id="divchange">
            <li><a class="homediv" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="div1" href="#div1">div1</a></li>
            <li> <a class="div2" href="#div2">div2</a></li>
            <li><a class="div3" href="#div3">div3</a></li>
            <li><a class="div4" href="#div4">div4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
    <script call>
```

And here is my controlling script

```
//Main site operation script
function fadeAll() {
    $("#homediv").fadeOut(600);
    $("#div1").fadeOut(600);
    $("#div2").fadeOut(600);
    $("#div3").fadeOut(600);
    $("#div4").fadeOut(600);
}
$(".div1").click(function() {
    fadeAll();
    $("#div1").delay(600).fadeIn(1500);
})
$(".homediv").click(function() {
    fadeAll();
    $("#homediv").delay(600).fadeIn(1500);
})
$(".div2").click(function() {
    fadeAll();
    $("#div2").delay(600).fadeIn(1500);
})
$(".div3").click(function() {
    fadeAll();
    $("#div3").delay(600).fadeIn(1500);
})
$(".div4").click(function() {
    fadeAll();
    $("#div4").delay(600).fadeIn(1500);
})
```

As it is the code works fine, but like I said, I want to be able to link directly to div4. Is that possible and if so, how?

Comment: Do a search on [client side routing](https://www.google.com/search?q=client+side+routing&oq=client+side+routing&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.755j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Right now the question is too broad because there are so many options to do what you need. Try something, then ask a more specific question. The gist of it is that you react to the URL changing, instead of reacting to clicks directly.

Comment: That gives me a direction to start looking. Thank you for the suggestion Juan.